# java swing tree not refresh after repaint

Tags: java, swing, resize, jtree, preferredsize

I want to apply chopping on to the node data of Tree after tree resize.
Node data always visible upto 70 % area of Tree.

Following is the code to add tree in scroll panel.

```
    tree = new JTree();     
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(711, 313));
    scrollPane.setMaximumSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());

    scrollPane.setViewportView(tree);
```

Following is the componnent resized event

```
@Override
public void componentResized(ComponentEvent arg0) { 
    TreeLeafUtil.setWidth((((int)(((JTree)arg0.getSource()).getWidth())))); 
    ((JTree)arg0.getSource()).repaint();
}
```

TreeLeafUtil.java

```
public String applyChooping(String recordValue){
    setNoOfCharecterToDisplay(recordValue);
    int maxLength = (recordValue.length() <= MAX_CHAR)? recordValue.length():(MAX_CHAR + 1);
    if (maxLength > MAX_CHAR) {
        recordValue = recordValue.substring(0, (maxLength - 1)) + "...";
    } else {
        recordValue = recordValue.substring(0, maxLength) ;
    }
    return recordValue;
}
private void setNoOfCharecterToDisplay(String displayStr){
    int actualLength = displayStr.length();
    if (actualLength > 0) {
        int reqWidth = fontMetrics.stringWidth(displayStr);
        //for one char
        int forOnechar = (reqWidth/actualLength);
        if (component == null) {
             MAX_CHAR =  (int) ((TreeLeafUtil.width  * 0.7)/forOnechar);   
        } else {
             MAX_CHAR =  (int) ((component.getWidth() * 0.7)/forOnechar);   
        }
    }

}
```

We have custome leaf node and contain toString method as follows

```
@Override
public String toString() 
     {
        return new TreeLeafUtil().applyChooping(video.getRecord());
     }
```

Comment: please whats .........

Comment: event from componentResized is fired from each of pixels, have to combine with Swing Timer

Comment: no.Could you please let me know how to modify the code.Mean while I will check Swing Timer

Comment: search here (in some cases with code in SSCCE form) by using java + swing + componentlistener,